# My code keeps deleting user scores and names

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im a newbie to programming and I've tried writing a simple code which is supposed to ask user a question and add a point if answer is correct or take away the point if answer is wrong. The problem occurs when I try saving score for the next time they open the " game ".

My code looks like this:

```
    from random import randint as ran
    from os import remove as rem
    from os import rename as ren
    
    name = input("Whats ur name?(the name is case sensitive)\n")
    sco = []
    i = -1
    s = 0
    NewUser = False
    update = open ("score.tmp", "w")
    getpoint = open ("score.txt", "r")
    
    for line in getpoint:
        a = line.split()
        sco.append(a)
    
    getpoint.close()
    
    try:
        for item in sco:
            i = i + 1
            if(sco[i][0]) == name:
                s = sco[i][1]
                break
            else:
                continue
    except:
        NewUser = True
    
    #some random code here
    
    if NewUser == True:
        with open ("score.txt", "a") as the:
            the.write(name + " " + str(s) + "\n")
    elif NewUser == False:
        sco[i][1] = s
        Update = (str(sco).strip("[]"))

        update.write(Update)
        rem("score.txt")
        update.close()
        ren("score.tmp", "score.txt")
```

Now in both cases ( NewUser == True and NewUser == False ) previous score in score.txt file gets deleted. Even a few days back when that same code " worked as it should " for some reason, for example if score.txt looked like this :

```
    Ann 100
    Daven 180
    Bella 90
    Brandon 80
```

the code would return this:

```
    [Ann], [100], [Daven], [180], [Bella], [90], [Brandon], [80]
```

and that makes it impossible for  program to function right next time when someone runs it :(

Please help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of this line:

```
update = open ("score.tmp", "w")
```

which opens file for writing, truncating it if exists. And this is your first access to that file, hence impression it was deleted. It just got zeroed.

As a fix, this line should be moved to be just before `write()` using it. Also, you are mixing `open()/close()` with pythonic `with open ...` - you should  try to stick to one style (and `with ...` is recommended way).

In general, do not attempt to access the same file at the same time using multiple handles, unless you know that's what you want.